# Error while uploading file on amazon s3 with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have a problem when I upload an image in carrierwave uploader

This is **config/initailizers/fog.rb**:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => '<redacted>',
    :aws_secret_access_key => '<redacted>'
    }

    config.fog_directory = 'illusioncalendar'
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"  
    config.fog_public = false 
    end
```

and this is **app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb**:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "illusioncalendar/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
     "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   end
  process :scale => [200, 300]

  version :thumb do
    process :scale => [200, 200]
  end

  version :small do
    process :scale => [48, 48]
  end

   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
   def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

end
```

And I have a mistake, when storage is fog, in file, i ran this successfully.
Thanks for any help. Regards!

Comment: What is the error? And the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

There could be other issues as well (we can't tell without the exact error or trace), but until then:

1. I don't know if this is a typo in your code or in your copypasta, but you're missing a comma after your aws_secret_access_key.
2. fog_directory shouldn't end in a slash.